# How to add an init script to h2 junit spring test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2, spring-boot-test

I have a  `@SpringBootTest` that makes use of an inmemory `h2` db for `junit` testing:

```
spring.datasource.cache.url=jdbc:h2:mem:;MODE=MYSQL
spring.datasource.cache.username=test
spring.datasource.cache.password=test
```

Question: how can I add an schema creation script to it on startup of the h2 db, but only for one or some tests?

Comment: Is there something in [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc) that didn't help you?

Comment: Yes: I don't want to load the schema for any test, but only for one specific test. So I'm looking for a initialization that can be applied per test, not per application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you can try using `@Sql` annotation on the test that would like to generate the schema/data/etc.

Give it a script that will contain schema definition and you're good to go.

```
@Sql("/generate_schema.sql")
public class MyTest {
}
```

Comment: Or load an `@ActiveProfile("junit-specific")` that features a `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema-specific.sql'`

Comment: By the way: both works. But if you're looking for schema generation *before* eg hibernate initialization kicks in, you have to use the `INIT=RUNSCRIPT` approach. Because `@Sql` is run *after* hibernate initialization.